# NancyFx+SignalR self host and Windows service

Tags: windows, service, signalr, nancy

Please help me to solve a problem. 
I use NancyFx and for code optimisation i decided to use only OWIN SelfHost 
without usage NancyFx SelfHost. 
I create windows service where i place code (OnStart function)

> ```
>  _s7Comm = _container.Resolve<IS7Comm>(); // s7 controller class connection
>  _context = Rhs60Hub.HubContext;          // hub context
>
> // events for send info to hub from s7
> _s7Comm.OnErrorEvent += S7CommOnErrorEvent; 
> ......
>
> var startup = _container.Resolve<Startup>(); // use Unity IoC 
>
> Service = WebApp.Start("http://+:8081/", startup.Configuration);
> ```

Start service with a help of Windows Service Helper - everythin is working. 
Do service stop, code (OnStop function)

> _s7Comm.OnErrorEvent -= S7CommOnErrorEvent;
>      .....
>
> _s7Comm.Dispose(); // free all tasks in object
>
> Service.Dispose(); // stop nancy

start again - branch with initialise NancyFX does not start but gives exception NullReferenceException.
my Start Class for Owin

> app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
>      app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration() { EnableDetailedErrors = true, EnableJSONP = true, EnableJavaScriptProxies = true });
>      app.UseNancy(options => options.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(UnityHelper.GetConfiguredContainer())); <- error here

For test I determine start of NancyFX with a help of package NancyFx SelfHost - all is good, start? stop and restar.

(OnStart function)

> _s7Comm = _container.Resolve(); // s7 controller class connection
>     _context = Rhs60Hub.HubContext;          // hub context
>
> // events for send info to hub from s7
>     _s7Comm.OnErrorEvent += S7CommOnErrorEvent; 
>     ......
>
> _host = new NancyHost(new Uri("http://localhost:8082"), new Bootstrapper(_container));
>
> _host.Start();
>
> var startup = _container.Resolve(); // use Unity IoC
>
> Service = WebApp.Start("http://+:8081/", startup.Configuration);

and remove string from Start class with definitions for nancyFx

Where can be a problem with usage host in OWIN? 
Code debuf shows that container is initialised and all dependencies are present. 
How I can discover with dependence is not present? Show you stack tracing

> >
>   в Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityDefaultBehaviorExtension.SetLifetimeManager(
>           Type lifetimeType, String name, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager)\r\n
>           в Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityDefaultBehaviorExtension.OnRegisterInstance
>           (Object sender, RegisterInstanceEventArgs e)\r\n
>           в System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)\r\n
>
>           в Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.RegisterInstance
>           (Type t, String name, Object instance, LifetimeManager lifetime)\r\n
>
>           в Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterInstance[TInterface](IUnityContainer container, TInterface instance, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager)\r\n
>
>           в Nancy.Bootstrappers.Unity.UnityNancyBootstrapper.RegisterBootstrapperTypes(IUnityContainer applicationContainer)\r\n
>
>           в Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperBase`1.Initialise()\r\n
>           в Nancy.Owin.NancyMiddleware.UseNancy(NancyOptions options)\r\n
>           в Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.UseNancy(IAppBuilder builder, NancyOptions options)\r\n
>           в Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.UseNancy(IAppBuilder builder, Action`1 configuration)\r\n
>           в RHS60SystemService.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>           в c:\......\Startup.cs:строка 16"    string

string 16 is

> app.UseNancy(options => options.Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(UnityHelper.GetConfiguredContainer()));

Answer (score 0):

What's the lifetime manager for the items you're resolving from `Unity`?  Are they the default `transient`, or are you using something else? [(Unity) Understanding Lifetime Managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx)

What's the actual error message of the exception (translated from Ukrainian/Russian, please ;) )

Are you/ do you need to `Dispose` of the `startup` instance as well?

Can you remove either Nancy or SignalR from the code, to try to establish which pipeline item is failing?